# Setting HTTP proxy in OpenVPN client

Tags: proxy, openvpn, http

I'm having trouble configuring my OpenVPN client to use an HTTP proxy.

If I don't enter any proxy information in the `client.ovpn` file I get the following output:

```
Mon Jun 29 14:30:07 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.7 i686-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Jun  8 2015
Mon Jun 29 14:30:07 2015 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015, LZO 2.08
Mon Jun 29 14:30:07 2015 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Mon Jun 29 14:30:07 2015 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Mon Jun 29 14:30:08 2015 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Mon Jun 29 14:30:08 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Mon Jun 29 14:30:08 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Mon Jun 29 14:30:08 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Mon Jun 29 14:30:08 2015 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Mon Jun 29 14:30:08 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Mon Jun 29 14:30:08 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon Jun 29 14:30:08 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:x
Mon Jun 29 14:30:08 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1435581008,WAIT,,,
Mon Jun 29 14:31:08 2015 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Mon Jun 29 14:31:08 2015 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Mon Jun 29 14:31:08 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Mon Jun 29 14:31:08 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1435581068,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,
Mon Jun 29 14:31:08 2015 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
```

Please note I replaced my actual VPN IP with x.x.x.x:x

This doesn't work because I'm behind a proxy.

When I edit the client.ovpn file accordingly (or atleast I thought) like this:

```
# If you are connecting through an
# HTTP proxy to reach the actual OpenVPN
# server, put the proxy server/IP and
# port number here.  See the man page
# if your proxy server requires
# authentication.
http-proxy-retry 1
http-proxy y.y.y.y 8080 (replaced actual IP here)
```

the VPN client does even less than before.
The log-output stays blank and it displays a messagebox saying: "Connecting to client has failed."

Afaik, the proxy IP is correct.  I can telnet to it on the 8080 port.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3):

try editing your .ovpn file like this.
put your tcp connection line under connection tag and define all needy_proxy here.

`<connection>
remote vpn_ip_here vpn_port tcp
http-proxy y.y.y.y 8080 (replaced actual IP here)
http-proxy-retry
</connection>`

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me via squid-proxy with basic user/pass auth, edit your .ovpn connection file as follow:

```
...
remote vpn_server_ip vpn_port tcp
http-proxy proxy_IP proxy_port auto
connect-retry-max 1
auth-nocache
<http-proxy-user-pass>
user
pass
</http-proxy-user-pass>
...
```

**Example:** 
openvpn server IP: 88.88.88.88 
openvpn server port: 443 
proxy server IP: 99.99.99.99 
proxy server port: 3128 
proxy username: user 
proxy password: pass

```
...
remote 88.88.88.88 443 tcp
http-proxy 99.99.99.99 3128 auto
connect-retry-max 1
auth-nocache
<http-proxy-user-pass>
user
pass
</http-proxy-user-pass>
...
```

this also works in my mobile openvpn app

Answer (score 0):

when we use openvpn via one proxy we can use this command:

http-proxy PROXY-IP PROXY-PORT auto

USERNAME

PASSWORD

if we need to connect two or more proxies in a row with a separate username and password, this command should be changed. For example, after connecting to the first proxy, connect to the next proxy server respectively and then establish a connection with the main VPN server. can you help me about this new command? thx.

thank you.